# woocommerce проблема добавления custom страницы в My Account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Код работает на localhost, но не работает на хостинге. (Страница Page not found WP). Версии WP,Woocommerce и Job Manager идентичные. Серверы Apache2. В чём может быть проблема? Спасибо

```
        function custom_wc_end_point() {
            if(class_exists('WooCommerce')){
            add_rewrite_endpoint( 'mysavedjobs', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
        }
        }
        add_action( 'init', 'custom_wc_end_point' );
        function custom_endpoint_query_vars( $vars ) {
            $vars[] = 'mysavedjobs';
            return $vars;
        }
        add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_endpoint_query_vars', 0 );
        function ac_custom_flush_rewrite_rules() {
            flush_rewrite_rules();
        }
        add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'ac_custom_flush_rewrite_rules' );

        function custom_endpoint_acct_menu_item( $items ) {

            $logout = $items['customer-logout'];
            $items['mysavedjobs'] = __( 'My saved jobs', 'woocommerce' ); 
                return $items;
        }
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'custom_endpoint_acct_menu_item' );

        function fetch_content_custom_endpoint() {

            echo do_shortcode("[my_bookmarks]");
        }
        add_action( 'woocommerce_account_mysavedjobs_endpoint', 'fetch_content_custom_endpoint' );
```

Comment: `WP_DEBUG` включен? Смотрели что говорит?

Comment: Как сайт переносили? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562/220220

Comment: @KAGG Design https://snapcreek.com/duplicator/?utm_source=duplicator_free&utm_medium=wp_org&utm_content=desc_details&utm_campaign=duplicator_free

Comment: Странным образом всё заработало. Предположительно на хостинге включён какой-то кеш и он обновился.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function custom_wc_end_point() {
        if(class_exists('WooCommerce')){
        add_rewrite_endpoint( 'mysavedjobs', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
        flush_rewrite_rules(); // Надо было добавить
    }
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'custom_wc_end_point' );
```